# Python folium add marker in random place

Tags: python, leaflet, javascript, folium

I would like to add a marker in a random place in Python folium.

I found the example, which I would like to implement, which is here:

http://kody.wig.pl/javascript/dodawanie-przesuwanie-i-kasowanie-markerow-leaflet/

but when I started to make it in Python folium, where my code look like this:

```
 mapJsVar = map.get_name()

 map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element("""

 <div class="marker-position">Click on the map and play with the marker</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 {map}.on('click',addMarker);
 </script>
 """.replace("{map}", mapJsVar)))
```

I have an error in my JavaScript console:

```
   **Uncaught ReferenceError: map_b6651fe88e04a627a682cee4dbed8fa4 is not defined**
```

I don't know why does it still appear, as I clearly declared the replacement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Folium injects the JS code to a place before the line where `map` object is created.

[image]

In the image, Line 1 is where folium adds the code. Line 2 is where the `map` object is created. Line 1 always run before Line 2. `map` object is called before defined, so you get the error.

Therefore, wrap the script to be injected always in `$(document).ready(function(){ __SCRIPT_HERE__ });`. This function ensures that the injected code is run after the `map` object is created.

Script:

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map()

mapJsVar = m.get_name()

m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element("""
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  {map}.on("click", addMarker);

  function addMarker(e) {
    // ustawiamy aby marker był przesuwalny
    const marker = new L.marker(e.latlng, {
      draggable: true,
    }).addTo({map});
  }
});

</script>
""".replace("{map}", mapJsVar)))

m
```

Demo:

[image]